# How do I parse through JSON Arrays in Kotlin

Tags: json, parsing, kotlin

so I am working on an Android app and I need to get a list of users from my mysql database and put their data into a User class in my kotlin app.

The php api is working correctly and I get this response with Postman in JSON:

```
{
    "id": "5f69bbc1b264c6.07041576",
    "username": "Test F",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "profileimagepath": "../uploads/profileimages/5f69bbc1b264c6.07041576.jpg"
}{
    "id": "5f69c5708632f7.37478122",
    "username": "Test H",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "profileimagepath": "../uploads/profileimages/5f69c5708632f7.37478122.jpg"
}
```

The user class in kotlin looks like this:

```
class UserItem(val id: String, val username: String, val email: String){
    constructor(): this("","","")
}
```

And the response listener for the https request looks like this:

```
val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,jsonObject,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                // Process the json
                try {
                    Log.d("loadTag", response.toString())
                    if(response.getString("error") == "false"){
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Loading completed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    else if(response.getString("error") == "true" && response.getString("message") == "Invalid code"){
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Invalid code.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                    else if(response.getString("error") == "true" && response.getString("message") == "Required Parameters are missing"){
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Invalid user details or fields are empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                    else if(response.getString("error") == "true"){
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error. Something went wrong. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

                }catch (e:Exception){
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Something went wrong. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

            }, Response.ErrorListener{
                // Error in request
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error in http request. Please contact the developer.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            })
```

I've tried so many things that I've read here and on other posts but I always only get one row (user "Test F")

**Update using Jackson**

I still get only one of the users using this code

```
when {
                        response.getString("error") == "true" && response.getString("message") == "Required Parameters are missing" -> {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Invalid user details or fields are empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                        response.getString("error") == "true" -> {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Something went wrong. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                        else -> {
                            val mapper = ObjectMapper()
                            val users: UserItem = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), UserItem::class.java)
                            System.out.println(users)
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Loading completed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                    }
```

I get my json response from the api through this code:

```
$stmt2 = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id,username,email FROM accounts WHERE id=?");
                $stmt2->bind_param("s", $friendsArray2);
                if($stmt2->execute()){
                    $result2 = $stmt2->get_result();
                    $num_of_rows2 = $result2->num_rows;
                    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
                        $index++;
                        $index2++;
                        echo json_encode($row2);
                    }
                }
```

There is more code but this is the part that gives me the response as I want the rows found in the sql statement

Comment: Json formatting is incorrect, there's niether array literal (`[...]`), nor comma between two json objects.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Yeah I got that now but I still don't know how to format it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used PHP for a while, but if I understand correctly you want to serve the array of Objects as Json.

```php
$stmt2 = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id,username,email FROM accounts WHERE id=?");
$stmt2->bind_param("s", $friendsArray2);
if($stmt2->execute()){
    $result2 = $stmt2->get_result();
    $num_of_rows2 = $result2->num_rows;
    $result_array = array();
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $index++;
        $index2++;
        result_array[] = $row2;
    }

    echo json_encode(result_array);  // echo or do whatever with the encoded json
}
```

This will push all the row data to the array, and finally will encode the data as a proper Json representation, then will echo (output) to the console/server.

And then you can easily decode the JsonArray into list using [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization):

```kotlin
@Serializable 
data class Project(val id: String, val username: String, val email: String)

// response <= the Json response body, you get from HTTP response
val list: List<UserItem> = JSON.parse(UserItem.serializer().list, response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Jackson to parse the JSON into an object, using ObjectMapper.readValue()

See here

https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-how-to-parse-json/

Whilst you're at it, use a when in Kotlin rather than a load of nested if statements.

Updated answer, with example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue

fun main() {

    val json = """
        [{
            "id": "5f69bbc1b264c6.07041576",
            "username": "Test F",
            "email": "test@gmail.com",
            "profileimagepath": "../uploads/profileimages/5f69bbc1b264c6.07041576.jpg"
        },{
            "id": "5f69c5708632f7.37478122",
            "username": "Test H",
            "email": "test@gmail.com",
            "profileimagepath": "../uploads/profileimages/5f69c5708632f7.37478122.jpg"
        }]
    """.trimIndent()

    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
    val userItems : List<UserItem> = mapper.readValue(json)

    println(userItems)
}

data class UserItem(val id: String, val username: String, val email: String,val profileimagepath: String)
```

Comment: Tried it and I still only get one of the users

Comment: What do you mean with "Whilst you're at it, use a when in Kotlin rather than a load of nested if statements"?

Comment: Covert your nested if's to a when. IntelliJ/Android Studio will do this for you if you hover over the statement.

Comment: How do I format my JSON response as an array? Isn't the response I get from my api already an array? I've updated the question, take a look at the code. And I like the tip of using when instead of if, thanks

Comment: It seems the interface has been updated to now require object type as the 2nd argument.  `mapper.readValue(json, SomeClass::class.java)`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `UserItem` to be a data class instead:

```kotlin
data class UserItem(
    val id: String,
    val username: String,
    val email: String
)
```

And then use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to convert JSON string into an array of objects:

```kotlin
import com.google.gson.Gson

val json = "{...}"
val response = Gson().fromJson(json, Array<UserItem>::class.java)
```

Comment: Doing this:           `val responsess = Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), Array<UserItem>::class.java)
                Log.d("Test", responsess.toString())`                          I get this error:`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

Comment: This is because your JSON isn't an array, it's two separate objects. Whatever is producing the JSON needs to create an array instead.

Comment: @GeorgeVasilache If the JSON you get is just one object, then change the type the Gson will deserialize it. For example, `Gson().fromJson(json, UserItem::class.java)` will deserialize it into a single object of `UserItem` type.

Comment: @Vitalii Plagov I updated the question, please take a look at it and tell me how to produce a json array. –