# How to create an arraylist from JSON in Kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I am new in Kotlin and I am trying to create an arraylist from a Json file, but I do not understand why it does not work.
This is my Json:

```
{
  "bottomApp": "com.android.contacts",
  "topApp": "com.android.chrome"
}{
  "bottomApp": "com.android.camera2",
  "topApp": "com.google.android.apps.docs"
}
```

And code. In the commets there are my attempts.

```
data class ApplicationInfo(
        var topApp: String? = null,
        var bottomApp: String? = null,
        var tIcon: Drawable? = null,
        var bIcon: Drawable? = null) {

companion object {

        internal inline fun <reified T> Gson.fromJson(json: String) = fromJson<T>(json, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)

        fun getShortcuts(context: Context, filename: String): ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> {
            var shortcutList = ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>()

            try {
                // Load data
                val jsonString = loadJson("dataj.json", context)
                val gson = Gson()
                // 1
                // val scType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>>() {}.type
                // shortcutList = gson.fromJson<ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>>(jsonString, scType)

                //2
                // shortcutList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Array<ApplicationInfo>::class.java).toList() as ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>

                //3
                shortcutList = gson.fromJson(jsonString.toString())


                Log.i("RESULT", shortcutList.toString())

                //Log.i("APPLIST", appList.toString())
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return shortcutList
        }

...
```

And the error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

Comment: You json file seems not an array

Comment: can share the full json file.or else that is the full file?

Comment: That is invalid Json representation, there's niether array literal (`[...]`), nor comma between two json objects.

Comment: Yes, this is the full file what I had created with gson:

Comment: Perhaps, you have same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64042170/11377112), I don't understand why people using PHP echo half of the json at a time...

Answer (score 0):

Hi your json file content must be

```
[
   {
      "bottomApp":"com.android.contacts",
      "topApp":"com.android.chrome"
   },
   {
      "bottomApp":"com.android.camera2",
      "topApp":"com.google.android.apps.docs"
   }
]
```